# Grouping the random effects reduces the total variance (misspecified random effects)

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the balanced crossed two-way ANOVA model with random effects:
$$
y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j + (\alpha\beta)_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}.
$$
Identify $(i,j)$ with a scalar index $h$, and set 
$$
\gamma_h = \alpha_i + \beta_j + (\alpha\beta)_{ij}.
$$
Now consider the balanced one-way ANOVA model $\mathcal{M}'$ with random effects:
$$
y_{hk} = \mu + \gamma_h + \epsilon_{hk}.
$$
A colleague of mine claims that some statisticians use the "simplified" model $\mathcal{M}'$ to estimate the total variance in $\mathcal{M}$. That is, with the R language, they do

```
M <- lmer(y ~ (1|Operator) + (1|Part) + (1|Operator:Part), data = dat)
dat$run <- dat$Operator:dat$Part
M' <- lmer(y ~ (1|run), data = dat)
```

Their motivation is to use the simplicity of the one-way model to calculate the estimate of the total variance by hand, or to get a confidence interval about the total variance.

*This approach is wrong*. Indeed, the $\gamma_h$ are correlated, while $\mathcal{M'}$ assumes they are independent.

Now, using simulations, I observed that the estimate of the total variance in $\mathcal{M'}$ is always smaller than the one in $\mathcal{M}$. I also observed that the two estimates of the total variance tend to be the same when the numbers of levels of the random effects become large.

Why? I'm interested in an intuitive explanation and a mathematical one.

---

Here is the code for the simulations:

```
library(lme4)

#' Simulate a two-way ANOVA design with random effects
#' @description Simulate a two-way ANOVA dataset with random effects.
#' @param I number of levels of first factor
#' @param J number of leveles of second factor
#' @param Kmin minimum number of repeats
#' @param Kmax maximum number of repeats
#' @param p numeric vector giving the probabilities to sample between
#' \code{Kmin} and \code{Kmax}
#' @param sigmaP standard deviation of first factor
#' @param sigmaO standard deviation of second factor
#' @param sigmaPO standard deviation of interaction
#' @param sigmaE residual standard deviation
#' @param factor.names names of the two factors
#' @param resp.name name of the response
#' @param keep.intermediate keep intermediate calculations in the output
#' @return A dataframe.
#'
#' @examples
#' SimDataAV2(I=3, J=2, Kmin=0, Kmax=2, p=c(0.1,0.2))
#'
#' @export
#' @importFrom stats rnorm
SimDataAV2 <- function(I, J, Kmin, Kmax, p=NULL, mu=0, sigmaP=1, sigmaO=1,
                       sigmaPO=1, sigmaE=1, factor.names=c("Operator","Part"),
                       resp.name="y", keep.intermediate=FALSE){
  Operator <- rep(1:J, each=I)
  Oj <- rep(rnorm(J, 0, sigmaO), each=I)
  Part <- rep(1:I, times=J)
  Pi <- rep(rnorm(I, 0, sigmaP), times=J)
  POij <- rnorm(I*J, 0, sigmaPO)
  simdata0 <- data.frame(Part, Operator, Pi, Oj, POij)
  simdata0$Operator <- factor(simdata0$Operator)
  levels(simdata0$Operator) <- 
    sprintf(paste0("%0", floor(log10(J))+1, "d"), 1:J)
  simdata0$Part <- factor(simdata0$Part)
  levels(simdata0$Part) <- sprintf(paste0("%0", floor(log10(I))+1, "d"), 1:I)
  II <- 0 ; JJ <- 0
  while(II<I | JJ <J){
    if(Kmin < Kmax){
      Kij <- sample(Kmin:Kmax, I*J, replace=TRUE, prob=c(p,1-sum(p)))
    }else{
      Kij <- rep(Kmin, I*J)
    }
    simdata <- droplevels(
      as.data.frame(
        sapply(simdata0, function(v) rep(v, times=Kij), simplify=FALSE)))
    JJ <- length(levels(simdata$Operator)); II <- length(levels(simdata$Part))
  }
  Eijk <- rnorm(sum(Kij), 0, sigmaE)
  simdata <- cbind(simdata, Eijk)
  simdata[[resp.name]] <- mu + with(simdata, Oj+Pi+POij+Eijk)
  levels(simdata[,1]) <- paste0("A", levels(simdata[,1]))
  levels(simdata[,2]) <- paste0("B", levels(simdata[,2]))
  names(simdata)[1:2] <- factor.names
  if(!keep.intermediate) simdata <- simdata[,c(factor.names,resp.name)]
  simdata
}

# simulated data
set.seed(666)
dat <- SimDataAV2(I=5, J=4, Kmin=3, Kmax=3)

# fit the two-ways model
fit1 <- lmer(y ~ (1|Operator) + (1|Part) + (1|Operator:Part), data = dat)
# sum of variance components
vc <- VarCorr(fit1)
do.call(sum, vc) + sigma(fit1)^2 # 4.46712

# fit the one-way model
dat$run <- dat$Operator:dat$Part
fit2 <- lmer(y ~ (1|run), data = dat)
# sum of variance of run effect and residual variance
vc <- VarCorr(fit2)
vc$run[1,1] + sigma(fit2)^2 # 4.154648
```

Comment: Very interesting post! I have a clarifying question. In the case of the fully crossed model (M), `lmer()` does not estimate correlations between the intercepts and that is not implied by the model. Yet you say that they are correlated. Can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: @ErikRuzek For instance, the grouped random effects $\alpha_1 + \beta_1 + (\alpha\beta)_{1,1}$ and $\alpha_1 + \beta_2 + (\alpha\beta)_{1,2}$ are correlated, because of the presence of $\alpha_1$ in each of them.

Comment: Can you post your simulation code ?